# Everytime different Url should be fetch

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to run one apps script that fetch the 10 URLs but not at same time ,that means in every one hour that script will run and in every run it will pick one URL from the spreadsheet that will contain the 10 URL and when the pointer reach to 10th URL then it again start from beginning .

Please help me on this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spreadsheet could record which URL has been fetched.  You could put a value in a cell next to the cell with the url with some value.  You could enter "true" or 1 or "yes" or "fetched", anything.

[image: Which URL fetched]

### Set The Triggers

[image: Current Triggers]
[image]

### Code:

```
/**
 * Retrieves all the rows in the active spreadsheet that contain data and logs the
 * values for each row.
 * For more information on using the Spreadsheet API, see
 * https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_spreadsheet
 */
function fetchURL_EveryHr() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[1];
 var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 10, 3);
 var values = range.getValues();

 // Print values

 for (var row in values) {
   for (var col in values[row]) {
     Logger.log(values[row][col]);
   }
 }


 for (var row in values) {

   Logger.log('values[row][2]: Row: ' + row + " : " + values[row][2]);
   Logger.log(values[row][1]);
   Logger.log('Column A: ' + values[row][0]);

   if (values[row][2] != "fetched") {
      Logger.log('It found a URL that has not been fetched!  On row:  ' + values[row][0]);

      //Get the URL
      var urlToFetch = values[row][1];

      Logger.log('urlToFetch: ' + urlToFetch);

      //Fetch the URL
      var fetchContentsData = UrlFetchApp.fetch(urlToFetch);
      // The code below logs the HTML code of the URL.

      Logger.log('fetchContentsData: ' + fetchContentsData);

      //Add a value to the cell
       var rowToSet = values[row][0];
       Logger.log('rowToSet: ' + rowToSet);

       var cellToSet = "C" + rowToSet;
       Logger.log('cellToSet: ' + cellToSet);

       var cell = sheet.getRange(cellToSet);
       cell.setValue("fetched");

      //Quit
      return;
   };
 };

 //If code gets to this point, all URL's have been fetched.  Start over again
 //Delete all the values in column C

   var ColC = sheet.getRange("C1:C10");
       ColC.setValue("");

};
```

Comment: If there is some error while fetching the url want to see in logs.

Comment: UrlFetchApp.fetch returns the HTTPResponse Class.  [Class HTTPResponse](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response) You can use the [getResponseCode()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response#getResponseCode()) method to determine if there is a response code that is something other than a success.  Also, if the fetch is successful, it's going to be quite long.  If you get back something empty, that might be another sign that it failed.